# Problem with AWS amplify library when deploying

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have a weird issue, where the app (react+vite+amplify+typescript) that I'm building runs perfectly locally, and it used to run perfectly in production too, until recently at least, now once i deploy it with

```
amplify publish
```

that runs

```
tsc && vite build
```

an error appears as soon as I try to load the page.

[image]

It's difficult to understand exactly where the error comes from, because since it happens only online, the app is already bundled in a single giant file, but by looks like it's inside the AWS library (either `aws-sdk` or `aws-amplify`, that are the only two included in the project)

I tried to update those libraries but nothing changes... any idea?